# How to plot the function 4(x)^2 = ((y)^2/(1-y))?

Tags: scilab

I want to plot the function

```
4(x)^2 = ((y)^2/(1-y));
```

how can I plot this?

```
--> 4*(x) = ((y^2)*(1-y)^-1)^0.5;
4*(x) = ((y^2)*(1-y)^-1)^0.5;
      ^^
Error: syntax error, unexpected =, expecting end of file
```

Comment: Where is your code? or attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to first create a function and for that you have to express one variable in terms of the other.

```
function x = f(y)
   x = (((y^2)*(1-y)^-1)^0.5)/4;
endfunciton
```

Then you need to generate the input data (i.e, the points at which you want to evaluate the function)

```
ydata = linspace(1, 10)
```

Now you push your input point through the function to get your output points

```
xdata = f(ydata)
```

Then, you can plot the pairs of x and y using:

```
plot(xdata, ydata)
```

Or even easier, without the intermediate step of generating the output data, you can simply do:

```
plot(f(ydata), ydata)
```

BTW. I find it strange that the function you are trying to plot is x in terms of y, usually, x is the input variable, but I hope you know what you are trying to accomplish.

Reference: https://www.scilab.org/tutorials/getting-started/plotting

Answer (score 2):

Since Scilab 6.1.0, plotimplicit() does it:

```
plotimplicit "4*x^2 = y^2/(1-y)"
xgrid()
```

Can't do more simple. Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take care that y must be in [-inf 1[

```
 y=linspace(-10 ,1.00001,1000);
 x = sqrt(y^2./(1-y))/4;
 clf; plot(y,x),plot(y,-x)
```

If x is a solution -x is also solution